# Java Apache POI Excel - Celula com valor Numérico e Double com Locale pt-BR

Tags: java, microsoft-excel, apache-poi, locale

Olá!

Estou fazendo uma planilha Excel em Java, que tem valores numéricos (double) a serem mostrados.
Preciso que o `CellType` seja `Numeric`, mas o único jeito que consigo mostrar o valor corretamente configurado, é com o `CellType` como `Geral` ou `Texto`.

O número vem do banco de dados já formatado corretamente (Ex: `412.000`). Aí, eu capturo ele como `double` e este double formata o número com `,` (`412,000`)

Eu já tentei: `NumberFormat`, `DecimalFormat`, `Locale`, `String.format`, etc, e embora o `CellType` esteja setado como `Numeric`, quando gera a planilha, o tipo da célula ou é `Geral` ou `Texto`.

O que estou fazendo atualmente é:

```
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(numeroCelula);
double value = 412.000; //Valor vindo do banco, mas o double troca para 412,000
cell.setCellType(CellType.NUMERIC);
cell.setCellValue(String.format("%.3f", value).replace(",", ".")); // valor em String, trocando , por . pra ficar correto.
```

Então, como eu consigo colocar o valor no nosso `Locale` (formatando os milhares com `.` ao invés de `,`) e setar o `CellType` como `Numeric`?

Desde já, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Existem alguns problemas com a maneira como você está imaginando a sua planilha. Dados do tipo `Texto` serão mostrados por seu visualizador de planilhas como forem escritos. Dados de tipo `Número`, não, visto que dependem da língua usada no programa.

Assim, há duas alternativas, mas você está misturando ambas: ou utiliza o valor do próprio `double`, sem pensar no significado de `.` ou `,`, visto que eles serão responsabilidade do software de exibição da planilha; ou utiliza o tipo `Texto`, configurando da maneira como desejar, mas correndo o risco de não apresentar o dado corretamente em outros *locales*.

Por fim, em sua implementação atual, a chamada de `setCellValue` com uma `String` troca o tipo da célula para `Texto`. Portanto, é necessário decidir por uma das implementações acima.